# html 5 canvas not displayed on iOS mobile safari

Tags: javascript, ios, svg, canvas, safari

i want to draw multiple SVGs on a canvas and then transform it into a png.
It works well on desktop chrome/FF or android chrome. 
But neither the canvas nor the png will show on mobile Safari (iOS 11.4).
As i don't work on a Mac, i cannot debug it on a Safari-browser. I read some stuff about problems with defining the canvas.width, but it is set in the html-Code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="432" height="452"></canvas>
        <div id="png-container"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var svgString1 = '<svg version="1.1" id="bgPolaroid11" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="215.734px" height="225.874px" viewBox="0 0 215.734 225.874" enable-background="new 0 0 215.734 225.874" xml:space="preserve"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.7822" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="&#9;M213.752,66.173c0.014-5.368,0.136-10.735,0.234-16.096c0.063-3.996,0.208-8.006,0.242-12.002c0.042-4.546-0.086-9.106,0.008-13.649&#9;c0.108-4.817,0.382-9.639,0.605-15.02c-0.133-1.942-0.25-4.449-0.474-6.934c-0.055-0.704-0.069-1.615-1.264-1.58&#9;c-3.042,0.111-6.096,0.152-9.133,0.229c-6.736,0.164-13.469,0.397-20.201,0.491c-8.151,0.104-16.282,0.066-24.425,0.136&#9;c-7.745,0.084-15.486,0.307-23.235,0.355c-15.1,0.097-30.196,0.118-45.293,0.192c-7.387,0.031-14.776,0.104-22.153,0.194&#9;C64.508,2.528,60.353,2.64,56.2,2.694c-6.241,0.095-12.48,0.126-18.71,0.23c-6.624,0.119-13.261,0.202-19.887,0.488&#9;C12.95,3.61,8.319,4.115,3.676,4.526C3.412,4.547,3.067,4.863,2.962,5.128c-0.156,0.378-0.181,0.828-0.181,1.26&#9;c0.052,5.629,0.136,11.25,0.181,16.89c0.066,8.817,0.094,17.641,0.157,26.472c0.031,4.915,0.098,9.823,0.104,14.738&#9;c0.021,6.426,0.104,12.837-0.035,19.267c-0.174,8.598-0.511,17.203-0.814,25.8c-0.369,10.652-0.801,21.282-1.139,31.934&#9;c-0.191,5.702-0.334,11.396-0.345,17.102c0,5.872,0.265,11.752,0.265,17.62c0,8.609-0.091,17.207-0.223,25.801&#9;c-0.098,6.199,0.445-19.377,0.351-13.186c-0.094,5.35-0.083,10.696-0.018,16.04c0.049,3.86,0.328,7.722,0.408,11.596&#9;c0.018,0.926,0.456,1.03,1.166,1.072c4.077,0.244,8.146,0.494,12.208,0.754c5.149,0.32,10.272,0.666,15.424,0.973&#9;c3.425,0.201,6.857,0.372,10.297,0.515c4.148,0.174,8.305,0.338,12.452,0.491c5.189,0.19,10.372,0.428,15.555,0.55&#9;c4.074,0.108,8.16,0.038,12.246,0.108c4.756,0.063,9.511,0.214,14.276,0.289c5.301,0.083,10.606,0.031,15.903,0.222&#9;c5.578,0.191,11.156,0.574,16.734,0.884c3.573,0.199,7.152,0.494,10.73,0.599c6.482,0.213,12.963,0.223,19.438,0.485&#9;c5.186,0.211,10.351,0.688,15.528,1.002c3.714,0.223,7.428,0.46,11.146,0.525c5.402,0.088,10.814,0.046,16.218,0.01&#9;c3.62-0.031,7.239-0.177,10.859-0.223c0.843-0.011,1.149-0.354,1.181-1.142c0.037-1.106,0.24-2.22,0.177-3.313&#9;c-0.473-7.108,0.292-14.168,0.445-21.247c0.07-3.94,0.216-7.867,0.356-11.807c0.138-4.262-0.563,23.259-0.396,19.005&#9;c0.174-4.762,0.546-9.518,0.557-14.262c0.034-6.45-0.216-12.89-0.317-19.34c-0.091-6.777-0.227-13.538-0.195-20.314&#9;c0.019-6.217,0.278-12.438,0.366-18.654c0.104-7.929,0.136-15.838,0.201-23.747c0.028-5.305,0.127-10.624,0.07-15.922&#9;c-0.042-4.608-0.271-9.217-0.369-13.826C213.839,75.495,213.739,70.837,213.752,66.173z M203.167,51.163&#9;c0,11.529-0.251,23.114-0.767,34.444c-0.918,20.287-0.104,40.88-0.957,61.131c-0.441,10.15-1.852,20.138-0.845,30.389&#9;c0.855,8.66-2.187,21.4,1.698,28.988c-4.525,0.335-8.473-0.664-12.901-1.105c-14.007-1.411-28.536,0.322-42.529,0.322&#9;c-16.478,0-32.703,0.868-49.104,0.868c-27.287,0-54.208-2.841-81.353-1.776c-1.475-6.415-0.159-15.386-0.159-22.242&#9;c0-8.379-1.219-16.354-0.418-24.638c0.62-6.426-0.97-19.271-0.97-19.271s0.679-11.145-0.77-16.899&#9;c-1.664-6.68-1.09-13.036-0.863-19.938c0.223-6.262-0.85-20.993-0.85-20.993s-0.432-20.583-0.432-31.882&#9;c0-4.587-0.01-8.994,0.884-13.332l-0.716-19.271c0,0,12.437-0.327,16.298-0.463c9.404-0.351,20.857-0.098,30.175-0.098&#9;c23.055,0,46.105-0.219,69.097,0.853c15.104,0.714,30.378,0.254,45.433,0.87c6.725,0.286,28.177-4.024,30.504,4.749&#9;c1.127,4.218-0.275,10.324-0.46,14.536C202.937,41.298,203.167,46.255,203.167,51.163z"/></svg>';              
    var svgString2 =  "<svg version=\"1.1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\"\t width=\"141.73px\" height=\"141.73px\" viewBox=\"0 0 141.73 141.73\" enable-background=\"new 0 0 141.73 141.73\" xml:space=\"preserve\"><g id=\"f_x5F_torso_x5F_01_x5F_20170111\">\t\t\t<path class=\"skin\" fill=\"#DDC1B6\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.4045\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM105.468,105.844c0,0-28.444-9.333-29.139-13.991c-0.691-4.658-0.691-7.986-0.691-7.986l-18.783,0.122\t\tc0,0,4.805,5.339,1.483,12.262c-3.325,6.921-13.858,9.048-23.137,13.576c0,0-10.522,4.658-2.215,23.03c0,0,2.851,7.684,2.712,9.28\t\th78.627c0,0,0.735-9.696,0.641-13.142C114.966,128.995,116.686,111.701,105.468,105.844z\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.4073\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM60.103,105.511c1.766,0.008,4.02-0.897,5.956-0.404c1.438,0.367,1.523,1.637,2.386,2.528c0.696,0.725,1.318,0.839,2.317,0.938\t\tc1.397,0.141,1.283,0.007,1.843-0.958c0.521-0.899,0.061-1.19,1.248-1.609c1.705-0.602,3.839,0.155,5.498-0.361\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.4073\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM44.505,126.64c0.258,0.54,0.171,1.635,0.29,2.298c0.213,1.183,0.769,2.218,1.099,3.372c0.302,1.053,0.919,2.184,1.169,3.215\t\tc0.243,1,0.123,5.568,0.123,6.612\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.4073\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM101.563,124.675c0,2.018,0.57,3.865,0.567,5.862c-0.003,2.128-0.284,9.488-0.284,11.6\"/></g><g id=\"f_x5F_kopf_x5F_01_x5F_20170111\">\t\t\t<path id=\"hals_4_\" class=\"skin\" fill=\"#DDC1B6\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.385\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM57.798,101.895c3.555-6.376-2.075-19.127-2.075-19.127l21.84-0.771c0,0-2.02,14.141,4.5,21.661\"/>\t\t\t<ellipse transform=\"matrix(-0.9926 -0.1215 0.1215 -0.9926 169.7558 146.7172)\" class=\"skin\" fill=\"#DDC1B6\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.385\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" cx=\"89.351\" cy=\"68.184\" rx=\"2.785\" ry=\"8.02\"/>\t\t\t<ellipse transform=\"matrix(0.9926 -0.1215 0.1215 0.9926 -7.9362 6.1373)\" class=\"skin\" fill=\"#DDC1B6\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.385\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" cx=\"46.372\" cy=\"68.163\" rx=\"2.786\" ry=\"8.019\"/>\t\t\t<path class=\"skin\" fill=\"#DDC1B6\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.385\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM68.211,95.744c3.604,0.295,5.861-1.068,11.637-6.768c5.045-4.982,8.227-11.152,9.139-23.264\t\tc1.332-17.691-7.324-31.517-20.836-31.517l-0.027,0.001c-13.512,0-22.269,12.411-21.374,30.132\t\tc0.597,11.794,4.093,18.974,9.14,23.955C61.662,93.982,65.021,96.002,68.211,95.744z\"/></g><g id=\"F-hair_x5F_50\">\t\t\t<path id=\"fhaare28frisur_1_\" fill=\"#FFFFFF\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.1327\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM52.252,87.484c0,0-0.428-0.666-0.938-1.781c-0.383-0.84-0.552-0.881-0.762-1.664c-0.164-0.609-0.434-1.209-0.653-1.803\t\tc-0.302-0.82-0.587-1.643-0.892-2.447c0.565,0.389,0.805,1.359,1.154,1.941c0.219,0.363,0.541,0.662,0.762,1.018\t\tc-0.451-1.025-1.047-1.998-1.5-3.02c-0.213-0.482-0.376-0.982-0.572-1.469c-0.177-0.441-0.229-1.186-0.544-1.512\t\tc-0.071,0.018-0.101,0.061-0.087,0.127c0.361,0.24,0.656,0.393,0.911,0.758c0.183,0.262,0.316,0.529,0.545,0.754\t\tc0.049-0.809-0.126-1.504-0.462-2.219c-0.432-0.912-0.684-1.877-1.134-2.773c-0.361-0.721-0.38-1.772-0.2-2.543\t\tc0.166-0.717,0.512-1.389,0.635-2.132c0.082-0.497,0.045-0.89,0-1.377c-0.035-0.376-0.201-0.874,0.052-1.195\t\tc0.362,0.144,0.638-0.536,0.748-0.829c0.239-0.018,0.442,0.113,0.692,0.117c0.712,0.014,0.67-0.607,1.136-0.829\t\tc0.257,0.626,0.985-0.201,1.218-0.382c0.342-0.264,0.561-0.055,0.947-0.203c0.684-0.262,0.261-0.986,1.153-0.859\t\tc0.549,0.078,1.071,0.306,1.614,0.4c0.781,0.136,1.686,0.08,2.484,0.043c0.318-0.016,0.641-0.094,0.95-0.008\t\tc0.331,0.093,0.657,0.461,1.009,0.277c0.376-0.197,0.484-1.103,0.645-1.469c0.234-0.537,0.354-0.859,0.353-1.464\t\tc-0.001-0.271-0.089-0.765,0.217-0.884c0.405,0.377,0.681,1.364,0.66,1.925c-0.015,0.378-0.145,0.745-0.171,1.124\t\tc-0.02,0.277-0.043,0.382,0.174,0.498c0.223,0.118,0.604-0.084,0.811-0.121c0.303-0.053,0.586-0.051,0.896-0.049\t\tc0.332,0.003,0.766,0.176,1.094,0.085c0.597-0.165,0.174-0.729,0.014-1.215c-0.238-0.726-0.836-1.382-0.238-2.002\t\tc0.482,0.493,0.711,1.589,0.752,2.302c0.022,0.396-0.041,0.611,0.31,0.788c0.327,0.165,0.813,0.085,1.169,0.085\t\tc0.66,0,1.324,0.024,1.98,0.08c0.82,0.07,1.633,0.166,2.412-0.119c0.217-0.08,0.462-0.297,0.673-0.342\t\tc0.158-0.033,0.328,0.066,0.494,0.048c0.375-0.041,0.42-0.101,0.793,0.041c0.393,0.149,0.889,0.338,1.318,0.285\t\tc0.518-0.063,0.393-0.33,0.393-0.786c0-0.78,0.027-1.68,0.74-2.168c0.17,0.635,0.02,1.67,0.422,2.211\t\tc0.33,0.445,1.096,0.439,1.555,0.208c0.561-0.282,0.42-0.417,0.939-0.166c0.609,0.296,1.229,0.016,1.889,0.04\t\tc0.371,0.014,0.93,0.094,1.256-0.145c0.287-0.21,0.242-0.329,0.24-0.698c-0.002-0.63-0.236-1.69,0.287-2.161\t\tc0.273,0.449,0.545,0.865,0.578,1.411c0.02,0.304-0.137,0.758,0.018,1.042c0.248,0.457,0.676,0.252,1.068,0.307\t\tc0.059,0.246,0.086,0.873,0.34,1.021c0.365,0.212,0.873-0.365,1.277-0.314c0.047,0.166,0.152,0.889,0.355,0.945\t\tc0.346,0.096,0.479-0.735,0.568-0.96c0.943,0.569,0.807,1.784,1.057,2.677c0.068,0.244,0.283,0.518,0.332,0.75\t\tc0.049,0.233-0.049,0.494-0.049,0.727c-0.004,0.426,0.064,0.822,0.004,1.251c-0.064,0.454-0.213,0.909-0.254,1.366\t\tc-0.049,0.537,0.047,1.045-0.029,1.584c-0.068,0.481-0.166,0.967-0.211,1.454c-0.217,2.379-0.834,4.637-1.51,6.91\t\tc-0.213,0.715-0.455,1.471-0.711,2.203c-0.25,0.715-0.619,1.463-0.828,2.197c0.426-0.521,0.715-1.145,1.164-1.652\t\tc0.258-0.291,0.504-0.541,0.658-0.906c0.133,0.717-0.031,1.482,0.133,2.182c0.02-0.279,0.178-0.547,0.357-0.754\t\tc0.271,0.379-0.914,0.533-1.02,0.969c-0.236,0.99-0.818,1.699-1.295,2.557c-0.486,0.875,7.168-4.477,7.748-13.053\t\tc0.582-8.624,2.502-12.95-0.748-26.866c0,0-0.791-12.543-11.791-15.793c0,0-8.954-4.291-21.121,0.25\t\tc-12.167,4.542-12.756,9.229-16.006,21.729c-2.892,11.119,6.521,25.094,5.695,36.415C48.275,90.857,52.252,87.484,52.252,87.484z\"\t\t/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM63.891,31.873c-2.732,0.241-6.357,3.331-8.275,5.27c-2.746,2.774-4.683,5.432-6.521,8.9c-2.679,5.055-4.044,10.852-2.371,16.496\"\t\t/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM57.057,39.705c-3.322,3.466-5.644,10.087-5.5,14.926c0.074,2.472,1.531,4.778,1.667,7.242\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM68.891,36.873c-0.842,2.88-3.268,5.139-3.943,8.144c-0.514,2.282-0.284,4.919-0.187,7.239c0.116,2.77,0.12,5.439,0.63,8.117\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM72.225,47.205c0.592,2.957,1.207,8.738,0.166,11.668\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM70.724,33.039c1.208,0.553,2.061,3.064,2.676,4.173c1.041,1.872,1.914,3.789,2.777,5.746c1.24,2.812,3.066,5.214,3.627,8.239\t\tc0.654,3.531,1.088,8.161,1.086,11.342\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM80.557,38.039c1.129,3.901,4.273,7.28,3.924,11.471c-0.162,1.947-0.129,3.492,0.182,5.443c0.406,2.57-0.293,4.444-0.771,6.92\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM86.057,44.039c-0.207,1.894,0.973,3.581,1.146,5.458c0.213,2.317,0.293,4.664,0.516,6.982c0.158,1.651,0.873,4.3-0.162,5.726\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM67.057,45.373c0,5.059-0.387,11.707,2,16.332\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM65.057,34.705c-4.164,2.81-7.158,9.76-7.842,14.609c-0.598,4.246,0.385,8.137,2.342,11.891\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM78.725,31.873c-1.066-0.443-1.867-1.57-3.025-1.838c-1.459-0.337-3.475,0.004-4.975,0.004c-3.616,0-7.263-0.644-10.678,0.707\t\tc-2.735,1.082-6.026,2.63-7.614,5.284c-1.189,1.991-3.001,5.097-3.041,7.343\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM83.391,34.539c1.846,2.16,3.121,5.391,4.326,7.932c1.18,2.487,1.771,4.336,2.166,7.063c0.561,3.883,1.504,7.574,1.674,11.512\t\tc0.17,3.908-0.021,7.621-1.166,11.323c-0.67,2.168-1.791,4.348-2.334,6.506\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM89.557,41.705c0.238,3.396,1.734,6.912,2.172,10.338c0.49,3.836,1.457,7.482,1.625,11.404c0.232,5.415-0.443,9.586-2.467,14.563\t\tc-0.705,1.736-1.482,3.482-2.482,5.066c-0.775,1.227-2.02,3.551-3.18,4.297\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM77.629,38.039c5.457,2.908,7.535,10.447,9.459,15.821c0.805,2.249,1.393,4.381,1.041,7.013c-0.23,1.731-0.992,3.277-1.186,4.977\t\tc-0.137,0.064-0.277,0.073-0.424,0.025c-0.195-1.389,1.26-3.109,1.654-4.502c0.346-1.221,0.188-2.088-0.002-3.287\t\tc-0.354-2.235-0.805-4.332-1.506-6.501c-0.789-2.438-1.965-4.868-3.324-7.05c-1.186-1.904-3.459-3.445-4.045-5.662\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM49.797,68.531c0-5.99-0.361-11.893,2.033-17.494c1.958-4.58,4.588-10.929,8.95-13.49c-1.617,1.702-3.896,2.441-5.292,4.576\t\tc-1.6,2.447-2.85,5.113-4.016,7.742c-1.844,4.16-2.455,9.606-1.342,14\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM45.565,70.078c0.036,1.029,0.875,2.45,1.313,3.399c0.563,1.217,0.991,2.561,1.356,3.834c0.847,2.955,0.515,6.236,1.329,9.242\t\tc0.385,1.424,0.446,2.904,0.811,4.334c0.35,1.371,0.551,2.805,0.756,4.205\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM44.981,71.494c-0.083,0.827,0.363,1.274,0.672,1.983c0.383,0.883,0.74,1.898,0.975,2.824c0.604,2.391,1.275,4.521,1.271,6.986\t\tc-0.004,2.059-0.011,4.064-0.088,6.127c-0.046,1.217-0.041,2.463,0.108,3.67c0.101,0.82,0.288,1.674,0.062,2.494\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM49.731,92.16c0.061,2.875,1.168,5.4,1.168,8.25\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM91.814,75.828c0,2.291-0.633,4.42-0.836,6.68c-0.188,2.076-0.459,4.145-0.563,6.24c-0.076,1.531-0.104,3.088-0.102,4.619\t\tc0.002,0.941-0.291,2.49,0.25,3.293\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM45.981,74.244c-0.023,0.086-0.003,0.137-0.096,0.201c0.73,1.117,1.11,2.781,1.513,4.049c0.392,1.232,0.544,2.494,0.734,3.775\t\tc0.421,2.834-0.384,5.055-2.317,7.225\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM92.232,74.078c-0.496,0.889-0.143,2.393-0.186,3.359c-0.111,2.486-0.42,4.816-0.85,7.248c-0.352,1.979-0.34,5.012,1.367,6.475\"/></g></svg>";


        var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
        var img1 = new Image();
        var svg1 = new Blob([svgString1], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
        var url1 = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg1);
        var img2 = new Image();
        var svg2 = new Blob([svgString2], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
        var url2 = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg2);
        var count = 2;

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



       /// image loading is async, make sure they are loaded
        img1.onload = img2.onload = function() {
            count--;
            if (count === 0) {
                drawImages();
                var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                document.querySelector('#png-container').innerHTML = '<img src="'+png+'"/>';
                DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
            }
        }

        img1.src = url1;
        img2.src = url2;


        /// when loaded, draw them somewhere on the canvas
        function drawImages() {
            ctx.drawImage(img2, 35, 64, 282, 282);
            ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, 432, 452 );
        }



    </script>
</body>
```

Anyone having an idea what to do?
Thx a lot, Fritz

Comment: You can run Safari on Windows.  It may not offer any help whatsoever, but it's worth trying.

Comment: i'll give it a try, thx

Comment: **Do not run Safari on Windows!** It's like running IE8 to test Edge. Beside the security risks connecting to the internet from this unmainted since 2012 virus catcher, it has **nothing** to do with **any** version of the macOs version. cc @Archer

Comment: @Kaiido Don't comment that nonsense at me.  He has a problem that may or may not be identified by Safari.  Just keep your tin foil hat handy and I'm sure it won't affect you one way or the other.

Comment: @Archer I *CC*ed you in case you really thought it was a good idea to use this thing as a way to test your code on Safari. It is not. Once again, it is like using IE8 to test Edge. I'm not sure what non-sense you are talking about, but what I know is that Apple has stopped the maintenance of this browser 6 years ago, That at this time, [they didn't even supported Blobs](https://caniuse.com/#search=blob) nor blobURIs yet. That this branch never had the same behavior than the osX one anyway, and that they had known security issues which will never get fixed.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm talking about your tin foil hat nonsense.  Fine, if you have reasonable objections as your clearly do (and I'm not arguing them), but to bring up security risks and virus concerns is like saying OP will drown if they pour a glass of water!

Answer (score 0):

Safari doesn't like your Blob's MIME Type.

The correct one is `image/svg+xml` the charset header is useless, and while I'm not sure it's actually allowed to be there, it is anyway useless.

So remove the `;charset=utf-8` part from your `type` option, and you'll be fine:

```js
var svgString1 = '<svg version="1.1" id="bgPolaroid11" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="215.734px" height="225.874px" viewBox="0 0 215.734 225.874" enable-background="new 0 0 215.734 225.874" xml:space="preserve"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.7822" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="&#9;M213.752,66.173c0.014-5.368,0.136-10.735,0.234-16.096c0.063-3.996,0.208-8.006,0.242-12.002c0.042-4.546-0.086-9.106,0.008-13.649&#9;c0.108-4.817,0.382-9.639,0.605-15.02c-0.133-1.942-0.25-4.449-0.474-6.934c-0.055-0.704-0.069-1.615-1.264-1.58&#9;c-3.042,0.111-6.096,0.152-9.133,0.229c-6.736,0.164-13.469,0.397-20.201,0.491c-8.151,0.104-16.282,0.066-24.425,0.136&#9;c-7.745,0.084-15.486,0.307-23.235,0.355c-15.1,0.097-30.196,0.118-45.293,0.192c-7.387,0.031-14.776,0.104-22.153,0.194&#9;C64.508,2.528,60.353,2.64,56.2,2.694c-6.241,0.095-12.48,0.126-18.71,0.23c-6.624,0.119-13.261,0.202-19.887,0.488&#9;C12.95,3.61,8.319,4.115,3.676,4.526C3.412,4.547,3.067,4.863,2.962,5.128c-0.156,0.378-0.181,0.828-0.181,1.26&#9;c0.052,5.629,0.136,11.25,0.181,16.89c0.066,8.817,0.094,17.641,0.157,26.472c0.031,4.915,0.098,9.823,0.104,14.738&#9;c0.021,6.426,0.104,12.837-0.035,19.267c-0.174,8.598-0.511,17.203-0.814,25.8c-0.369,10.652-0.801,21.282-1.139,31.934&#9;c-0.191,5.702-0.334,11.396-0.345,17.102c0,5.872,0.265,11.752,0.265,17.62c0,8.609-0.091,17.207-0.223,25.801&#9;c-0.098,6.199,0.445-19.377,0.351-13.186c-0.094,5.35-0.083,10.696-0.018,16.04c0.049,3.86,0.328,7.722,0.408,11.596&#9;c0.018,0.926,0.456,1.03,1.166,1.072c4.077,0.244,8.146,0.494,12.208,0.754c5.149,0.32,10.272,0.666,15.424,0.973&#9;c3.425,0.201,6.857,0.372,10.297,0.515c4.148,0.174,8.305,0.338,12.452,0.491c5.189,0.19,10.372,0.428,15.555,0.55&#9;c4.074,0.108,8.16,0.038,12.246,0.108c4.756,0.063,9.511,0.214,14.276,0.289c5.301,0.083,10.606,0.031,15.903,0.222&#9;c5.578,0.191,11.156,0.574,16.734,0.884c3.573,0.199,7.152,0.494,10.73,0.599c6.482,0.213,12.963,0.223,19.438,0.485&#9;c5.186,0.211,10.351,0.688,15.528,1.002c3.714,0.223,7.428,0.46,11.146,0.525c5.402,0.088,10.814,0.046,16.218,0.01&#9;c3.62-0.031,7.239-0.177,10.859-0.223c0.843-0.011,1.149-0.354,1.181-1.142c0.037-1.106,0.24-2.22,0.177-3.313&#9;c-0.473-7.108,0.292-14.168,0.445-21.247c0.07-3.94,0.216-7.867,0.356-11.807c0.138-4.262-0.563,23.259-0.396,19.005&#9;c0.174-4.762,0.546-9.518,0.557-14.262c0.034-6.45-0.216-12.89-0.317-19.34c-0.091-6.777-0.227-13.538-0.195-20.314&#9;c0.019-6.217,0.278-12.438,0.366-18.654c0.104-7.929,0.136-15.838,0.201-23.747c0.028-5.305,0.127-10.624,0.07-15.922&#9;c-0.042-4.608-0.271-9.217-0.369-13.826C213.839,75.495,213.739,70.837,213.752,66.173z M203.167,51.163&#9;c0,11.529-0.251,23.114-0.767,34.444c-0.918,20.287-0.104,40.88-0.957,61.131c-0.441,10.15-1.852,20.138-0.845,30.389&#9;c0.855,8.66-2.187,21.4,1.698,28.988c-4.525,0.335-8.473-0.664-12.901-1.105c-14.007-1.411-28.536,0.322-42.529,0.322&#9;c-16.478,0-32.703,0.868-49.104,0.868c-27.287,0-54.208-2.841-81.353-1.776c-1.475-6.415-0.159-15.386-0.159-22.242&#9;c0-8.379-1.219-16.354-0.418-24.638c0.62-6.426-0.97-19.271-0.97-19.271s0.679-11.145-0.77-16.899&#9;c-1.664-6.68-1.09-13.036-0.863-19.938c0.223-6.262-0.85-20.993-0.85-20.993s-0.432-20.583-0.432-31.882&#9;c0-4.587-0.01-8.994,0.884-13.332l-0.716-19.271c0,0,12.437-0.327,16.298-0.463c9.404-0.351,20.857-0.098,30.175-0.098&#9;c23.055,0,46.105-0.219,69.097,0.853c15.104,0.714,30.378,0.254,45.433,0.87c6.725,0.286,28.177-4.024,30.504,4.749&#9;c1.127,4.218-0.275,10.324-0.46,14.536C202.937,41.298,203.167,46.255,203.167,51.163z"/></svg>';
var svgString2 = "<svg version=\"1.1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\"\t width=\"141.73px\" height=\"141.73px\" viewBox=\"0 0 141.73 141.73\" enable-background=\"new 0 0 141.73 141.73\" xml:space=\"preserve\"><g id=\"f_x5F_torso_x5F_01_x5F_20170111\">\t\t\t<path class=\"skin\" fill=\"#DDC1B6\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.4045\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM105.468,105.844c0,0-28.444-9.333-29.139-13.991c-0.691-4.658-0.691-7.986-0.691-7.986l-18.783,0.122\t\tc0,0,4.805,5.339,1.483,12.262c-3.325,6.921-13.858,9.048-23.137,13.576c0,0-10.522,4.658-2.215,23.03c0,0,2.851,7.684,2.712,9.28\t\th78.627c0,0,0.735-9.696,0.641-13.142C114.966,128.995,116.686,111.701,105.468,105.844z\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.4073\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM60.103,105.511c1.766,0.008,4.02-0.897,5.956-0.404c1.438,0.367,1.523,1.637,2.386,2.528c0.696,0.725,1.318,0.839,2.317,0.938\t\tc1.397,0.141,1.283,0.007,1.843-0.958c0.521-0.899,0.061-1.19,1.248-1.609c1.705-0.602,3.839,0.155,5.498-0.361\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.4073\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM44.505,126.64c0.258,0.54,0.171,1.635,0.29,2.298c0.213,1.183,0.769,2.218,1.099,3.372c0.302,1.053,0.919,2.184,1.169,3.215\t\tc0.243,1,0.123,5.568,0.123,6.612\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.4073\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM101.563,124.675c0,2.018,0.57,3.865,0.567,5.862c-0.003,2.128-0.284,9.488-0.284,11.6\"/></g><g id=\"f_x5F_kopf_x5F_01_x5F_20170111\">\t\t\t<path id=\"hals_4_\" class=\"skin\" fill=\"#DDC1B6\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.385\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM57.798,101.895c3.555-6.376-2.075-19.127-2.075-19.127l21.84-0.771c0,0-2.02,14.141,4.5,21.661\"/>\t\t\t<ellipse transform=\"matrix(-0.9926 -0.1215 0.1215 -0.9926 169.7558 146.7172)\" class=\"skin\" fill=\"#DDC1B6\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.385\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" cx=\"89.351\" cy=\"68.184\" rx=\"2.785\" ry=\"8.02\"/>\t\t\t<ellipse transform=\"matrix(0.9926 -0.1215 0.1215 0.9926 -7.9362 6.1373)\" class=\"skin\" fill=\"#DDC1B6\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.385\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" cx=\"46.372\" cy=\"68.163\" rx=\"2.786\" ry=\"8.019\"/>\t\t\t<path class=\"skin\" fill=\"#DDC1B6\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.385\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM68.211,95.744c3.604,0.295,5.861-1.068,11.637-6.768c5.045-4.982,8.227-11.152,9.139-23.264\t\tc1.332-17.691-7.324-31.517-20.836-31.517l-0.027,0.001c-13.512,0-22.269,12.411-21.374,30.132\t\tc0.597,11.794,4.093,18.974,9.14,23.955C61.662,93.982,65.021,96.002,68.211,95.744z\"/></g><g id=\"F-hair_x5F_50\">\t\t\t<path id=\"fhaare28frisur_1_\" fill=\"#FFFFFF\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0.1327\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM52.252,87.484c0,0-0.428-0.666-0.938-1.781c-0.383-0.84-0.552-0.881-0.762-1.664c-0.164-0.609-0.434-1.209-0.653-1.803\t\tc-0.302-0.82-0.587-1.643-0.892-2.447c0.565,0.389,0.805,1.359,1.154,1.941c0.219,0.363,0.541,0.662,0.762,1.018\t\tc-0.451-1.025-1.047-1.998-1.5-3.02c-0.213-0.482-0.376-0.982-0.572-1.469c-0.177-0.441-0.229-1.186-0.544-1.512\t\tc-0.071,0.018-0.101,0.061-0.087,0.127c0.361,0.24,0.656,0.393,0.911,0.758c0.183,0.262,0.316,0.529,0.545,0.754\t\tc0.049-0.809-0.126-1.504-0.462-2.219c-0.432-0.912-0.684-1.877-1.134-2.773c-0.361-0.721-0.38-1.772-0.2-2.543\t\tc0.166-0.717,0.512-1.389,0.635-2.132c0.082-0.497,0.045-0.89,0-1.377c-0.035-0.376-0.201-0.874,0.052-1.195\t\tc0.362,0.144,0.638-0.536,0.748-0.829c0.239-0.018,0.442,0.113,0.692,0.117c0.712,0.014,0.67-0.607,1.136-0.829\t\tc0.257,0.626,0.985-0.201,1.218-0.382c0.342-0.264,0.561-0.055,0.947-0.203c0.684-0.262,0.261-0.986,1.153-0.859\t\tc0.549,0.078,1.071,0.306,1.614,0.4c0.781,0.136,1.686,0.08,2.484,0.043c0.318-0.016,0.641-0.094,0.95-0.008\t\tc0.331,0.093,0.657,0.461,1.009,0.277c0.376-0.197,0.484-1.103,0.645-1.469c0.234-0.537,0.354-0.859,0.353-1.464\t\tc-0.001-0.271-0.089-0.765,0.217-0.884c0.405,0.377,0.681,1.364,0.66,1.925c-0.015,0.378-0.145,0.745-0.171,1.124\t\tc-0.02,0.277-0.043,0.382,0.174,0.498c0.223,0.118,0.604-0.084,0.811-0.121c0.303-0.053,0.586-0.051,0.896-0.049\t\tc0.332,0.003,0.766,0.176,1.094,0.085c0.597-0.165,0.174-0.729,0.014-1.215c-0.238-0.726-0.836-1.382-0.238-2.002\t\tc0.482,0.493,0.711,1.589,0.752,2.302c0.022,0.396-0.041,0.611,0.31,0.788c0.327,0.165,0.813,0.085,1.169,0.085\t\tc0.66,0,1.324,0.024,1.98,0.08c0.82,0.07,1.633,0.166,2.412-0.119c0.217-0.08,0.462-0.297,0.673-0.342\t\tc0.158-0.033,0.328,0.066,0.494,0.048c0.375-0.041,0.42-0.101,0.793,0.041c0.393,0.149,0.889,0.338,1.318,0.285\t\tc0.518-0.063,0.393-0.33,0.393-0.786c0-0.78,0.027-1.68,0.74-2.168c0.17,0.635,0.02,1.67,0.422,2.211\t\tc0.33,0.445,1.096,0.439,1.555,0.208c0.561-0.282,0.42-0.417,0.939-0.166c0.609,0.296,1.229,0.016,1.889,0.04\t\tc0.371,0.014,0.93,0.094,1.256-0.145c0.287-0.21,0.242-0.329,0.24-0.698c-0.002-0.63-0.236-1.69,0.287-2.161\t\tc0.273,0.449,0.545,0.865,0.578,1.411c0.02,0.304-0.137,0.758,0.018,1.042c0.248,0.457,0.676,0.252,1.068,0.307\t\tc0.059,0.246,0.086,0.873,0.34,1.021c0.365,0.212,0.873-0.365,1.277-0.314c0.047,0.166,0.152,0.889,0.355,0.945\t\tc0.346,0.096,0.479-0.735,0.568-0.96c0.943,0.569,0.807,1.784,1.057,2.677c0.068,0.244,0.283,0.518,0.332,0.75\t\tc0.049,0.233-0.049,0.494-0.049,0.727c-0.004,0.426,0.064,0.822,0.004,1.251c-0.064,0.454-0.213,0.909-0.254,1.366\t\tc-0.049,0.537,0.047,1.045-0.029,1.584c-0.068,0.481-0.166,0.967-0.211,1.454c-0.217,2.379-0.834,4.637-1.51,6.91\t\tc-0.213,0.715-0.455,1.471-0.711,2.203c-0.25,0.715-0.619,1.463-0.828,2.197c0.426-0.521,0.715-1.145,1.164-1.652\t\tc0.258-0.291,0.504-0.541,0.658-0.906c0.133,0.717-0.031,1.482,0.133,2.182c0.02-0.279,0.178-0.547,0.357-0.754\t\tc0.271,0.379-0.914,0.533-1.02,0.969c-0.236,0.99-0.818,1.699-1.295,2.557c-0.486,0.875,7.168-4.477,7.748-13.053\t\tc0.582-8.624,2.502-12.95-0.748-26.866c0,0-0.791-12.543-11.791-15.793c0,0-8.954-4.291-21.121,0.25\t\tc-12.167,4.542-12.756,9.229-16.006,21.729c-2.892,11.119,6.521,25.094,5.695,36.415C48.275,90.857,52.252,87.484,52.252,87.484z\"\t\t/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM63.891,31.873c-2.732,0.241-6.357,3.331-8.275,5.27c-2.746,2.774-4.683,5.432-6.521,8.9c-2.679,5.055-4.044,10.852-2.371,16.496\"\t\t/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM57.057,39.705c-3.322,3.466-5.644,10.087-5.5,14.926c0.074,2.472,1.531,4.778,1.667,7.242\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM68.891,36.873c-0.842,2.88-3.268,5.139-3.943,8.144c-0.514,2.282-0.284,4.919-0.187,7.239c0.116,2.77,0.12,5.439,0.63,8.117\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM72.225,47.205c0.592,2.957,1.207,8.738,0.166,11.668\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM70.724,33.039c1.208,0.553,2.061,3.064,2.676,4.173c1.041,1.872,1.914,3.789,2.777,5.746c1.24,2.812,3.066,5.214,3.627,8.239\t\tc0.654,3.531,1.088,8.161,1.086,11.342\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM80.557,38.039c1.129,3.901,4.273,7.28,3.924,11.471c-0.162,1.947-0.129,3.492,0.182,5.443c0.406,2.57-0.293,4.444-0.771,6.92\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM86.057,44.039c-0.207,1.894,0.973,3.581,1.146,5.458c0.213,2.317,0.293,4.664,0.516,6.982c0.158,1.651,0.873,4.3-0.162,5.726\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM67.057,45.373c0,5.059-0.387,11.707,2,16.332\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM65.057,34.705c-4.164,2.81-7.158,9.76-7.842,14.609c-0.598,4.246,0.385,8.137,2.342,11.891\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM78.725,31.873c-1.066-0.443-1.867-1.57-3.025-1.838c-1.459-0.337-3.475,0.004-4.975,0.004c-3.616,0-7.263-0.644-10.678,0.707\t\tc-2.735,1.082-6.026,2.63-7.614,5.284c-1.189,1.991-3.001,5.097-3.041,7.343\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM83.391,34.539c1.846,2.16,3.121,5.391,4.326,7.932c1.18,2.487,1.771,4.336,2.166,7.063c0.561,3.883,1.504,7.574,1.674,11.512\t\tc0.17,3.908-0.021,7.621-1.166,11.323c-0.67,2.168-1.791,4.348-2.334,6.506\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM89.557,41.705c0.238,3.396,1.734,6.912,2.172,10.338c0.49,3.836,1.457,7.482,1.625,11.404c0.232,5.415-0.443,9.586-2.467,14.563\t\tc-0.705,1.736-1.482,3.482-2.482,5.066c-0.775,1.227-2.02,3.551-3.18,4.297\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM77.629,38.039c5.457,2.908,7.535,10.447,9.459,15.821c0.805,2.249,1.393,4.381,1.041,7.013c-0.23,1.731-0.992,3.277-1.186,4.977\t\tc-0.137,0.064-0.277,0.073-0.424,0.025c-0.195-1.389,1.26-3.109,1.654-4.502c0.346-1.221,0.188-2.088-0.002-3.287\t\tc-0.354-2.235-0.805-4.332-1.506-6.501c-0.789-2.438-1.965-4.868-3.324-7.05c-1.186-1.904-3.459-3.445-4.045-5.662\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM49.797,68.531c0-5.99-0.361-11.893,2.033-17.494c1.958-4.58,4.588-10.929,8.95-13.49c-1.617,1.702-3.896,2.441-5.292,4.576\t\tc-1.6,2.447-2.85,5.113-4.016,7.742c-1.844,4.16-2.455,9.606-1.342,14\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM45.565,70.078c0.036,1.029,0.875,2.45,1.313,3.399c0.563,1.217,0.991,2.561,1.356,3.834c0.847,2.955,0.515,6.236,1.329,9.242\t\tc0.385,1.424,0.446,2.904,0.811,4.334c0.35,1.371,0.551,2.805,0.756,4.205\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM44.981,71.494c-0.083,0.827,0.363,1.274,0.672,1.983c0.383,0.883,0.74,1.898,0.975,2.824c0.604,2.391,1.275,4.521,1.271,6.986\t\tc-0.004,2.059-0.011,4.064-0.088,6.127c-0.046,1.217-0.041,2.463,0.108,3.67c0.101,0.82,0.288,1.674,0.062,2.494\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM49.731,92.16c0.061,2.875,1.168,5.4,1.168,8.25\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM91.814,75.828c0,2.291-0.633,4.42-0.836,6.68c-0.188,2.076-0.459,4.145-0.563,6.24c-0.076,1.531-0.104,3.088-0.102,4.619\t\tc0.002,0.941-0.291,2.49,0.25,3.293\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM45.981,74.244c-0.023,0.086-0.003,0.137-0.096,0.201c0.73,1.117,1.11,2.781,1.513,4.049c0.392,1.232,0.544,2.494,0.734,3.775\t\tc0.421,2.834-0.384,5.055-2.317,7.225\"/>\t\t\t<path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#594D45\" stroke-width=\"0.3116\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" d=\"\t\tM92.232,74.078c-0.496,0.889-0.143,2.393-0.186,3.359c-0.111,2.486-0.42,4.816-0.85,7.248c-0.352,1.979-0.34,5.012,1.367,6.475\"/></g></svg>";


var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
var img1 = new Image();
var svg1 = new Blob([svgString1], {
  type: "image/svg+xml" // no ';charset=utf-8'
});
var url1 = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg1);
var img2 = new Image();
var svg2 = new Blob([svgString2], {
  type: "image/svg+xml" // no ';charset=utf-8'
});
var url2 = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg2);
var count = 2;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



/// image loading is async, make sure they are loaded
img1.onload = img2.onload = function() {
  count--;
  if (count === 0) {
    drawImages();
    var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.querySelector('#png-container').innerHTML = '<img src="' + png + '"/>';
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
  }
}

img1.src = url1;
img2.src = url2;


/// when loaded, draw them somewhere on the canvas
function drawImages() {
  ctx.drawImage(img2, 35, 64, 282, 282);
  ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, 432, 452);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="432" height="452"></canvas>
  <div id="png-container"></div>
</div>
```